# How to fetch first N rows from table based on filter condition sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to retrieve first 500 records for each matching ids. I tried following query, but it retrieves total 500 records., not 2500. Each id has more than 500 records.

Example:

```
select id from table where id in (1,2,3,4,5) and rownum <= 500
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) analytical function to get a unique row number for each record in a partition and then limit the rows in outer query.

Here is an example from emp Table-

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*,
               ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY ename)
                  row_num
          FROM emp a)
 WHERE row_num <= 3;
```

- In above query, row_number function will return a unique number for
  rows in particular department.
- `Where clause` in outer query will filter result-set to max 3 records per department.